# Can not implicitly convert type system.collection.genaric.list<Cuisine> to DataModel.resturant.cuisine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I find many other questions on the same problem but I can't get any solution

This is my handler function for searching a cuisine in database

```
    public Cuisine GetCuisines(string cuisine)
    {

        using (ResturantContext context = new ResturantContext())
        {
            // db.Cuisines.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(Cuisine))
            return (from m in context.Cuisines
                       .Include("Images")
                       .Include("Category")
                    where m.Name == cuisine
                    select m).ToList();
        }
    }
```

what is the problem here I can't find out

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault() instead of ToList() or change the return type of the method to List<Cuisine>.

Comment: What the error message is trying to tell you is that you're returning a list, but your method is declared as returning a single item. It helps to figure out how to read error messages, the answer is usually in there already even if it may sometimes be a bit cryptic.

Comment: You could at least be clear enough (in the question, not in comments on answers) whether you are expecting multiple results or just one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToList()` creates a `List<Cuisines>` but your method returns a single `Cuisine`.

You should either change the return type of the method to `List<Cuisines>`:

```
public List<Cuisine> GetCuisines(string cuisine)
```

...or call `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `ToList()` to select only a single `Cuisines`:

```
using (ResturantContext context = new ResturantContext())
{
    return (from m in context.Cuisines
                .Include("Images")
                .Include("Category")
            where m.Name == cuisine
            select m).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

`FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if no matching `Cuisines` was found. `Single()` will throw an exception.

Comment: Depending on how the callers will use this, it may be better to use `SingleOrDefault()` or even `Single()` to get an exception when the data does not match expectations.

Comment: @hvd: True but it's usually preferable get a null reference back than getting an exception.

Comment: @mm8 Null vs. exception depends on how the callers will use this (on whether the `cuisine` parameter is always expected to be found in the database), both are defensible. But consider also two records being found with the same name. There, randomly picking one of the two is covering up a huge problem and will lead to further problems down the road when e.g. the addition of an index in the database suddenly causes a different object to be returned. There, I highly recommend ensuring an exception gets thrown.

Comment: @hvd: It's a matter of taste really. I did include the Single()/exception in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a return type `List<Cuisine>` instead of `Cuisine`:

```
public List<Cuisine> GetCuisines(string cuisine)
```

Comment: thanks bro this helped me out

Answer (score 1):

use FirstOrDefault for get one item

```
public Cuisine GetCuisines(string cuisine)
{

    using (ResturantContext context = new ResturantContext())
    {
        // db.Cuisines.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(Cuisine))
        return (from m in context.Cuisines
                   .Include("Images")
                   .Include("Category")
                where m.Name == cuisine
                select m).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to get list of cuisine searched by a customer

Comment: Then you wrong the return type,  you have to set an IEnumerable

Comment: the below answer solved my problem thanks bro